# referencing python libraries in a separate folder

Tags: python

Im pip-ing all my libraries to a folder called lib. My source code is in the directory scr.

My directory structure

```
Folder
    -lib
       -different libraries
    -scr
       -main.py
```

I just want to reference my libraries so my code will run.

Comment: What does "pip-ing all my libraries to a folder" mean? How are you installing them there? And, just as importantly, why?

Comment: From `main.py`, use `HERE = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))`, then use `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(HERE, '..', 'lib')))` to update your `sys.path` to include the other folder. That way you get to include the correct absolute folder whatever the current path of `Folder` might be.

Comment: Im using codebuild. when i pip the libraries i have to store them someone so i can reference them in my lambda. Is that not correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sys` module to append the path.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/Folder/src')
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to append a path to Python's system path:

```
import os.path
import sys
sys.path += [os.path.abspath('../lib')]
import my_lib
```

Comment: This assumes that the current working directory is `Folder`. Do not rely on the current working directory.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Nope, `src`. It relies on a relative path, which is a good way to organize a project.

Comment: Sorry, yes, `Folder/src`. No, relative paths like these are resolved against something that is not part of the project, the *current working directory*. You can't count on the current working directory being `Folder/src`. It could be somewhere else on the filesystem entirely, at which point `os.path.abspath('../lib')` will be resolved to an incorrect path. Do not rely on the current working directory.

Comment: Instead, explicitly resolve your paths against a path derived from `__file__`. For example, `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))`. `__file__` can be an absolute or relative path, but if it is a relative path, then Python will have set it as relative to the current working directory, so can be relied upon to be resolved correctly.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: "somewhere else on the filesystem entirely" was not the question. The good part about Python is not over-generalizing.

Comment: I'm trying to tell you that your code **won't work in many situations**, because you are assuming that the current working directory will always be set to the path of `src`. That is simply not the case, so your answer is, unfortunately, incomplete.